# Coloring a TextBox in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have a table in my report and want to color my Header which is a textbox.
Coloring must be conditional and  i am having problem in writing expression.

right now i am using

```
Switch(Fields!Value.Value="196","GREEN",Fields!Value.Value="197","GRAY",Fields!Value.Value="194","RED",Fields!Value.Value="195","RED",Fields!Value.Value="193","RED")
```

and there are 4 ROWS in the table with following values

- 197
- 197
- 197
- 196

Using the above expression header is having Gray color.

What i want is that If any of the 4 values is 193 OR 194 OR 195 then the color of the Header must be RED else Green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a bit gimmick solution, but you could create this inside your dataset query.

Create a calculated column that is 1 if the specified column is between 193 and 195 and 0 otherwise.

Then inside your report you can take sum of that column and if that sum is > 0 then you color header red.

Answer (score 0):

try this code with `If` statement for information you can also do it with `switch`

first go to : textbox properties 
[image]

then select :
[image]

and write this code in the expression

```
 =IIF((Fields!Value.Value=193) or (Fields!Value.Value=194) or (Fields!Value.Value=195),"Red","LimeGreen")
```

Comment: thank you, 
This takes into consideration only the first value of the column.

Comment: that I understood if the value = 193 or the value = 194 or the value = 194 the color will be Red else the value will be Green 
that's right ?

Comment: yes but must consider all the rows in the coloum . not only the first row.

Comment: i added some picture can  you test the method in the picture

Comment: Yes i did exactly the same.